# MySQL script to delete data in chunks until everything lower then id has been deleted

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I need an MySQL Skript which does the following:

delete chunks of the database until it has deleted all link_id's greater then 10000

exmaple:

```
x = 10000
DELETE FROM pligg_links WHERE link_id > x and link_id < x+10000
x = x + 10000
...
```

So it would delete

```
DELETE FROM pligg_links WHERE link_id > 10000 and link_id < 20000
```

then

```
DELETE FROM pligg_links WHERE link_id > 20000 and link_id < 30000
```

until all id's less then 10000 have been removed

I need this because the database is very very big (more then a gig)

thank in advance

Comment: check my updated answer it will solve your problem

Comment: No same error still coming up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the problem in ::

```
DELETE FROM pligg_links WHERE link_id > 10000
```

There is another way of doing it:(Just execute these 3 queries in order)

```
Step1 : Insert into pligg_links_temp select * from pligg_links where link_id < 10000;
Step2 : Drop pligg_links;
Step3 : Insert into pligg_links select * from pligg_links_temp
```

Comment: Its to big to delete it all at once!

Comment: believe me I tried that and the whole server and all sites stop working (I waited 1 hour before I restarted the server)

Comment: That `DROP` wants to be a `TRUNCATE`, I think :)

Comment: no, it will be a drop because in the step 3 u are implicitly creating the table

Comment: I get the following error: #1146 - Table 'chris123_pligg.pligg_links_temp' doesn't exist

Comment: SAME ERROR: Insert into pligg_links_temp select * from pligg_links WHERE `link_id` > 0 and link_id < 10000;

Comment: or u do 1 thing get the create table script from "Show create table tablename" and rename and create a new temp_table with the name mentioned above, then follow the steps

Comment: could you please tell me what I have to past into the sql query for that to work thanks! after that the answer should be yours ;)

Comment: Insert into pligg_links_temp select * from pligg_links where link_id < 10000;
truncate pligg_links;
Insert into pligg_links select * from pligg_links_temp

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12737/discussion-between-chriswede-and-sashi-kant)

Comment: this approach will break your foreign keys also.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `LIMIT` statement to regulate how many items to delete in one step:

```
DELETE FROM pligg_links
WHERE link_id > 10000
LIMIT 1000;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html says:

> The MySQL-specific LIMIT row_count option to DELETE tells the server
>   the maximum number of rows to be deleted before control is returned to
>   the client. This can be used to ensure that a given DELETE statement
>   does not take too much time. You can simply repeat the DELETE
>   statement until the number of affected rows is less than the LIMIT
>   value.

You could determine the number of deleted rows by using `SELECT ROW_COUNT();` if you would like automatize deletion:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Comment: @biziclop so will I have to run this my self every time or will it loop automatically?

Comment: It won't loop automagically, to loop, you can create a mysql stored procedure, or maybe a small php script. Or consider Sashi Kant's second one-step solution, if possible.